# Change how list web part is displayed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

We have some executives who need to have a list setup exactly the way they want it and I have not been able to find anyway to do this after multiple days of searching.

Is it possible to make a SharePoint list web part to display as below instead of the normal view?

Normal view.

```
Poster name and pic|    Post|      Comment count
```

Wanted view

```
Pic    Name
tu     Post
re     Comment count
```

And then the next post would be the same format underneath the other post.

I have access to SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On view for example `AllItems.aspx` click Library > Modify View.

Under **Style** choose **Document details** and click **OK**

**EDIT**
For custom list is different.

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-list-view-styles.html

Try Boxed.

Comment: The only options I have in the style tab are:
Basic Table
Boxed, no labels
Boxed
Newsletter
Newletter, no lines
Shaded
Preview Pane

Comment: You sir/mam are awesome the boxed view works.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, the only possibility OOTB that I know about which will allow you to change the way a list item is displayed is like so:

Go to the list/library settings
Scroll down to views
click on the view and go to the Style tab and expand it and choose the style that works best for you.

Furthermore, I am sure that there are some webparts out there that give you custom list view styles.

[image]

Comment: And since you are using a web part, you can just show the specific list view.